# Xcode 6.0.1 Cancel button unwind segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am following the apple developer tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html but it is using xcode 5, whilst I am on 6.0.1. I am having trouble linking the cancel button and done button to the exit, I can Control-Drag from the button but when it hovers over the exit and I let go nothing happens.

This part is almost at the bottom of the page in the link I have added.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have already defined/created the exit method in your view controller:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
{
    NSLog(@"Segue unwind 'done'…");
}
```

If you have your method with that signature i.e. `methodName:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue` the Xcode will find it, and you see something like this when you do the drag:

[image]

Comment: I still can't get it to work, these are my view controller parts which I THINK are relevant, I am still a complete novice here so forgive me if I am wrong. ViewController.h: - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue; ViewController.m: - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"Segue unwind 'done'…");
}

Comment: Is the `unwindToList` method in `ViewController.h` in the controller for the view you want to unwind to?

Comment: It is in the ViewController.h of the view I want to unwind to.

Comment: That's weird, the only thing I can think of is asking have you saved the `viewcontroller.m` file after adding the method? Failing that try and clean the project (Shift-Command-K)

Comment: I have uploaded it to google drive, you should hopefully be abel to access this, these are all the files in the Xcode Project. Hopefully you can open the folder straight into Xcode presuming you can download this, thanks so much for your help so far https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B97_-mjmKRQrZ2dVd2tlaW9kN0E&usp=sharing please do say if you cannot download the files

Comment: I don't use google drive, and the web interface doesn't seem to have a download option.

Comment: I assume you have an email, if you tell me it I will email you the folder which contains the files

Comment: Its broken to me on XCode 6.0.1 and 6.1GM as well. Even on a project with dozens of existing unwind segues, nothing shows up in the list of Exit options.